# Symfony 3 bind data to form from request

Tags: php, symfony, angular, put

I have a small question, how should I bind PUT request in symfony to form, if `Request` is empty.

Even if I get access to data with

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

I have got incorrect structure to bind data and `$form->handleRequest` will not work as expected. There is no form name and hierarchy is not observed. 
I get an object of post from angular interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you submit the data to form directly, which in essence is done within `handleRequest()` call.

The official docs says how to do it: **[Calling Form::submit() manually](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html#calling-form-submit-manually)**

If need be you could even "submit" all the fields individually, but that is very unlikely to happen to anyone.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. Anyway, I have to lead data to the required structure for entity? With key of form name for every field? Or how ?
Or it can be like this
[ 'entity_property' =>  'value property']

Comment: Yes, you won't need form name as wrapper, but everything else needs to match the form. As far as I know, all the standard rules of validation apply, so if you have a `name` field and you supply `myName` you will eventually get an error regarding "extra fields"...